# Kallax: package is not in any of the go paths

Tags: go, gopath

I have tried to use [kallax](https://github.com/src-d/go-kallax). When I tried to run that, I caught an error like this:

```
panic: parseutil: package is not in any of the go paths

goroutine 1 [running]:
gopkg.in/src-d/go-kallax.v1/generator.glob..func1(0x890120, 0xc00015af60)
    /home/user/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/src-d/go-kallax.v1@v1.3.5/generator/template.go:491 +0xa2
```

`GOPATH` is set to `/home/user/go`, besides I use vendoring `GO111MODULE=on`.
Could you tell me what did I wrong? Or how can I install parseutil package to `PATH`?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that you have `GO111MODULE=ON`. You will need to change it to `auto` (or `off`) and re-run the Kallax install in a non-module path (a directory that does not have a `go.mod` file present in that directory or any parent directory).

For example:

```sh
cd ~
export GO111MODULE=auto
go get -u gopkg.in/src-d/go-kallax.v1/...
```

or in fish shell:

```
cd ~
set -x GO111MODULE auto
go get -u gopkg.in/src-d/go-kallax.v1/...
```